# Drupal 8 Permission to see Structure > Menu

Tags: users, navigation

Drupal 8. I want a user with a certain role to be able to see and administer menu items /admin/structure/menu/manage/main

On the permissions page /admin/people/permissions I have 'Administer menus and menu items' checked. This worked in Drupal 7.

I can get to the /admin/structure/menu/manage/main page if I manually type in in the browser.

But the 'Structure' button/link does not appear in the toolbar for that role. It shows up for me when am logged in as User/1

How do I get the 'Structure' in the Toolbar? Am I choosing the wrong permission? Am I missing one?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You would have to grant the following permissions to the role:

##### Required

- *Use the toolbar*
- *Administer menus and menu items*
- *Use the administration pages and help*

##### Optional

- *View the administration theme*

Comment: This is totally correct, but fyi- If a person is using the Admin Toolbar (it creates dropdown menus in the Toolbar), adding the permission to 'user the administration pages and help' will make all the Toolbar links visible. For example, the person would see the 'Configuration' link/button and all its children, even if a person does not have access.  When you go to that section it will just say 'You do not have any administrative items'. This is a known issue with the Admin Toolbar. There is a separtate module you can install to hide them https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_links_access_filter

Comment: Here's a link to the issue where there is a working patch: https://www.drupal.org/node/2855786

Comment: That patch has been added to Admin Toolbar as the Admin Toolbar Links Access Filter submodule. Enable it and the Configuration menu isn't shown.